# Converting from UTF8 To ASCII in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, ascii

I have written a code to read data from a text file. I would like to know how to convert from UTF8 to ASCII after loading the data from the file. Below is part of the code that I have written but need to find the way to do the conversion. As I said in my previous questions I'm very new to Java, please give me a hand.

```
public static List<String> readFile(String filename) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();


    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));



    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        records.add(line.trim());
    }


    bufferedReader.close();
    return records;
}
```

Comment: UTF8 to ascii conversion is not well defined as utf8 has many more characters than in ascii. In your conversion, what do you want to do if you encounter a UTF8 character that is not an ascii character?

Comment: Are you referring to the base ASCII character set, or one of the many *enhanced* ASCII character sets? If just the base, and your data *can* be stored in base ASCII, then no conversion is needed, since Unicode includes all the base ASCII characters with same code point values.

Comment: yeah the base character set, but in my original file I have characters like this:  Šaltenis, Simonas

Comment: Your code reads with the user's  default character encoding (which is who knows) and stores as Java string (which is UTF-16). Why are you asking about ASCII and where would that come into your program?

Comment: have you checked my code in the link? I have a complex text file and all I want is to improve the interpolation search performance

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding for the Unicode character set. ASCII is an encoding for the ASCII character set. It seems that your question is less about encodings than sets of characters. You read a UTF-8 encoded text file (into UTF-16 encoded strings), incorrectly, I guess, using the [user's default encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileReader.html). Do want to **transliterate** from all of the Unicode characters to a subset, such just the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your original code:

```
public static List<String> readFile(String filename) throws Exception {
String line = null;
List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();


BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));



while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    records.add(line.trim());
}


bufferedReader.close();
return records;
}
```

change it to:

```
public static List<String> readFile(String filename) throws Exception {
   return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
}
```

remember to import the relevant java.nio packages or your program will give you a compilation error.

Here's a fully working program:

```
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Tests {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String filename = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test.txt";
            try {
                for(String s : readFile(filename)) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static List readFile(String filename) throws Exception {
            return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there any utility  I need to import? I get a message saying: cannot find symbol - variable paths

Comment: @CosaRamirez It's located here: java.nio.file.Paths. So go ahead and import java.nio* and java.nio.file* to the beginning of your class

Comment: ok I did that now I get the following:  cannot find symbol-  variable StandardCharsets

Comment: @CosaRamirez Import java.nio.charset.* too

Comment: can you please show me what to do in the while loop and at the end of the method

Comment: I compiled and no syntax errors but when I run it I get: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Comment: and below that: at q5.readFile(q5.java:51)
 at q5.main(q5.java:18)

Comment: @CosaRamirez I updated my answer again with a working program. I've tested it on my machine and had no errors. If you need further help, I think you need to post the contents of the file you're trying to read as well to assess what the problem really is. Try running the sample program I posted in my answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: thanks for your help man: here is the link to the program and the file. The file is to large to post it here https://github.com/Cosa34/interpolation-and-binary-